# Jenkins (Bitbucket Team/Project) - java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList - after end of Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I have a "Bitbucket Team/Project" and Jenkinsfile is recognized and stages are running fine (sonarqube,testing, checkout).
However when pipeline is completely finished I got the following exception and build ist marked as FAILURE while the whole time it was SUCCESS.

The strange thing ist that pipeline was running sometimes succesfull and not I always get this error message.

**ERROR Case**

```
...
[Pipeline] echo
 ### End of Jenkinsfile
 ### 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ansiColor
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@dbb1a61
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@524ef10
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@1c8283c0
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@2f0774ce
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@681bad7c
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@7eb3bb8e
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4fba8a5a
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4fba8a5a
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:569)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor669.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor669.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:140)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:459)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:435)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:423)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:363)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**SUCCESS Case**

```
[Pipeline] // ansiColor
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Question**
How can I find out the reason for this error?
I do not change a GitChangeSetList actively in my Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Can you show more of your `Jenkinsfile`? Something is presumably not `Serializable` and the pipeline bombs out with `NotSerializableException` and the post-notification is fired.

Comment: argh thanks mkobit. I found the piece in Jenkinsfile (I was using `currentBuild.changeSets`) and fixed it as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417906/jenkins-pipeline-exception-java-io-notserializableexception-hudson-model-freest. Thanks anyway